# Strange Char* Truncation

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm just getting back into C programming, and I'm having a strange problem with a dynamic char* field in a struct. It starts off completely fine, and the right length, but it's getting truncated to 25 characters the last of which isn't even in the original array.

I have two structs defined and a couple of global variables:

```
struct files_list {
  struct files_list* next;
  char* fpath;
};

struct job_list {
  int len;
  off_t size;
  struct files_list* files;
  struct job_list* next;
};

struct job_list* job_head = NULL;
struct job_list* active = NULL;
```

(The idea is that there will be a single linked list of "jobs" that multiple threads will process that each consist of a single linked list of files for that job.)

Main just calls `ntfw` to walk a directory tree:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // ...
  nftw("/tmp/", populate, 100, 0);
  // ...
}
```

For every file and directory, ntfw calls my `populate` function:

```
int populate(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
             int tflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf) {



  if (tflag == FTW_F) {
    /* #1 CREATE NEW FILE ENTRY */
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("FPATH: %s\n", fpath);
    struct files_list* current_files = malloc(sizeof(struct files_list));
    current_files->fpath = malloc(sizeof(fpath) + 1);
    strcpy(current_files->fpath, fpath);
    current_files->next = NULL;
    printf("files_list %s (%i)\n", current_files->fpath, strlen(current_files->fpath)); 
    printf("&current_files: %p\n", current_files);



    /* #2 CREATE NEW ACTIVE JOB */
    if (active == NULL) {
      struct job_list* job = malloc(sizeof(struct job_list));
      job->len = 0;
      job->size = 0;
      job->files = NULL;
      job->next = NULL;
      active = job;
    }
    active->len++;
    active->size += sb->st_size;


    /* #3 INSERT FILE ENTRY AT THE END OF ACTIVE JOB */
    if (active->files == NULL) {
      active->files = current_files;
      printf("&active->files: %p\n", active->files);
      printf("current_files->fpath: %s (%i)\n", current_files->fpath, strlen(current_files->fpath)); // TRUNCATED STRING
      printf("active->files->fpath: %s (%i)\n", active->files->fpath, strlen(active->files->fpath));
    } else {                                                                                                                                                                                               
      struct files_list* x = active->files->next;                                                                                                                                                                  
      while (1) {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        if (x == NULL) {                                                                                                                                                                                           
          x = current_files;                                                                                                                                                                                       
          printf("Added files_list: %s\n", x->fpath);                                                                                                                                                              
          break;                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
          printf("next x->next\n");                                                                                                                                                                                
          x = x->next;                                                                                                                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      }
    }

    /* #4 TIME FOR A NEW JOB */
    if (active->size > MAX_BYTES) {
      if (job_head == NULL) {
        job_head = active;
        job_tail = active;
      } else {
        job_tail->next = active;
      }
      struct job_list* new_active = NULL;
      active = new_active;
      job_len++;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

That produces output like this:

```
FPATH: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.T8MuMk/SingletonSocket
files_list /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.T8MuMk/SingletonSocket (46)
&current_files: 0x125d1e0
&active->files: 0x125d1e0
current_files->fpath: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.1 (25)
active->files->fpath: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.1 (25)
```

As we can see from the first two lines, the file path is long, contains 46 characters, and was successfully `strcpy()`ed into my `files_list` struct. Then something happens between step #2 and the first couple lines of step #3 that truncates the file name to 24 characters and adds a "1." The pointer addresses show that it's still the same struct object, and I don't see any operations that could possibly mess with it.

I've used GCC 4.9.2 and Clang 3.5.0, and they both have this problem, so it must be something that I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Comment: `current_files->fpath = malloc(sizeof(fpath) + 1);` You're allocating `sizeof(char*) + 1` bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem

```
malloc(sizeof(fpath) + 1);
```

`sizeof(fpath)` will give the size of a pointer since `fpath` is a `char *` i.e. a `char` pointer, you need `strlen()`

```
malloc(strlen(fpath) + 1);
```

don't forget to include `string.h`.

You need to read about the `sizeof` operator, this is from the 1570 draft, **§ 6.5.3.4** paragraph **¶ 2**.

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

**Note**: you must check the return value from `malloc()` family of functions, they return `NULL` when failure happens, and you must check the return value of pretty much every function that has one, because it's the only way to ensure that the function worked and nothing unexpected happened, otherwise why would there be a return value for it?

Comment: Agree with what @iharob says about checking. It might seem as if it doubles the work you have to do but when you have 1000 function calls in your mega program and it malfunctions the effort pays off. But it's *more* than that. Developing a programming style that will cope when things don't go the way you expect, leads to robust code. If you invest the time from the outset, to test every small development, to stress it, try to break it, in the long run you'll get the pay-off, especially if your product is being used in a live situation that has to be debugged and updated on-the-fly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That does work, and I understand the problem. However, `malloc()` was not returning NULL, though, and the initial assignment contained the full string. I can't wrap my head around why it works initially and then breaks at that later point.

Comment: That's called undefined behavior, and it's undefined so it will work one time, and not another time, I didn't mean that `malloc()` was returning `NULL`, it's just advice, get used to checking `malloc()`'s return value, it will be good for you in the long run , read WeatherVane's comment.